# Should I travel to US or switch my organization for better challenges?

Tags: software-industry, job-change, travel

I'm from India, working for a avionics company (Headquarter at US)  since last three years. 
At start my career I was involved in software development (Matlab/Simulink/C). The work was pretty exciting and challenging for two years.

Now since last year the work is no longer challenging/interesting. Its all about issues/minor bug fixation/support for old/legacy projects.

I'm a good performer and have contributed to a great extent to all project in which I was involved. I also was "Engineer of Year" last year.

My employer is now sending me to US for at-least 6 months, consoling me that I'll learn and get training on new design aspects. These training too will be on legacy projects. And I feel like I'm loosing all my skill-sets.

I am very keen in projects involving C/C++ /Data Structures SW development, which my current organization hardly have any and therefore I'm planning to prepare well and switch to any other reputed firm, which have such kind of projects.

Any suggestion regarding opting for US Travel or switching organization will be appreciated.

Comment: **down-voters** please explain a valid reason why this question is not appropriate here, IMO,many people suffer from this dilemma, for whom just travelling around world and earning money is not sole motive in life.Also, if its duplicate please provide a link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You work for a USA company, but are working in India.   They are effectively using your office as an outsourcing resource for the work they don’t think is important enough to use they own employees on.

Even if you work for a “native” company, unless that company does more then provide cheap staff to other companies you will get the same problem.

It is well known in the “west” that most India developers cannot produce useful results unless there is a very well defined spec – **maintenance tasks tend to have a well defined spec**.  We used to call code written by the India outsourcing company “yes man” code – as they would never question what they were asked to do, just produce software that was no use to anyone.   (Therefore it was best for us, if we somehow stop the management getting them to do anything important.)

So you need to work for a company that does not depend on work from outside of India, or work for one of the few western companies that developers complete products in India from concept right though to sale and support.

Comment: I'd suggest revising your answer, as it makes your own experience ("we used to call...") into a general rule ("it is well known...") - and no, it is not 'well known'. I also think it's borderline offensive, but that's just me: if the specs aren't clear it's not the fault of the offshore developers, but you make it sound like it is. Lastly, you don't really answer the question: are you suggesting to switch for a company that does not outsource? The original question asked about 'switching organisation', but did not say 'moving away from India'.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is: go while you can. I suppose a six-month relocation period is OK with you, which either means you don't have a family that needs you or your family is OK as well.

A six-month work period in the US will be an enlightening experience for you. Yes, as you say

> My employer is now sending me to US for at-least 6 months, consoling
>   me that I'll learn and get training on new design aspects. These
>   training too will be on legacy projects. And I feel like I'm loosing
>   all my skill-sets

...you *might* lose six months of skill-set development, but you'll gain other much more significant experience points (XP):

- First-hand experience of another culture.
- First-hand experience of "what happens on the other side" - this will be extremely useful when you come back to India, as you'll have a clearer picture of the rationale behind certain demands.
- You'll get to know different colleagues, and possibly make friends - an invaluable asset if your company is growing. In fact, as you are working on your career, your friends will be working on this and in a few years you might find yourself to be a close friend of a CEO.
- A relocation offer is a near-promotion: they believe in you to the point where they are investing in you. At least, you owe them a trip to check out why.

Worst case scenario you'll have seen the US for six months (good luck getting a tourist visa for that long... and I'm talking with first hand experience here) and will have a clear idea why you are *not* moving there.

Also, what do you have to lose? :)